# how do i contact a Facebook user with their Facebook_id?

Tags: php, facebook

Does anyone know if there's anyway to reach Facebook users using their facebook_id?

Background:
I have a web app.  Many of my users logon using their Facebook_id.  When they create their account they're also supposed to provide an email address, but a few of them haven't done this (I think it's my fault, and that the UI needs some work).  So now I'd like to contact them and tell them that I need their email address.  (The email address is actually a critical part of the app.)

I know how to post to their Facebook wall (the app does this), but this seems like a poor way to reach them.

I'm using php.

Any ideas?  Thanks....

Comment: you can request to have access to their email address when they grant your app access. I would think this is quicker than asking them to also add their email address manually.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=USERID

(replace USERID with actual number)

Comment: This will actually work, thanks!  I can manually type this address into my web browser and send each users a message.  Does anyone know if I can send a message via php though?  Then I could automate the task.

Comment: This is a very useful answer, thanks! But there is an issue. Facebook users may change the "Who can send you Facebook messages" setting (it's under 'Privacy settings' > 'How you connect') so that going to their profile page needn't provide a 'Message' button.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to contact a Facebook user is trough a method she/he granted you permission for, otherwise you are most probably breaching the TOS and are in danger of being reported.

The best way to proceed is to display a mandatory form to fill in an e-mail address next time the targeted users log in, this way you get the e-mails for all the active users and don't bother the inactive ones.